# Dynamically set baseUrl in cypress.json

Tags: laravel, cypress

I have a laravel app and have brought in Cypress testing. In my `cypress.json` file I have the `baseUrl` value set to a string of `localhost:8000`. The issue is the cypress test baseUrl will change based on which environment I am on (Local, Production etc...) so is there a way to set this `baseUrl` dynamically in the `cypress.json` file? I ask about the Laravel `.env` because the baseUrl or `APP_URL` is already set there.

Thanks.

Current cypress.json

```
  "baseUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8000", //How to make this dynamic based on app environment?
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
```

Comment: Can you add your `cypress.json` file to the question?

Comment: @AlapanDas done. It's a very basic file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can change the value of the baseURL from the cli something like this:

```js
npx cypress run --config baseUrl=https://example.com/
```

Or, a better approach would be to create multiple commands under scripts tag in your `package.json` like this:

```js
"scripts": {
  "test": "cypress run",
  "test:staging": "cypress run --config baseUrl=https://staging-example.com/",
  "test:prod": "cypress run --config baseUrl=https://prod-example.com/"
}
```

And then you can directly run:

```js
npm run test:staging
npm run test:prod
```

Comment: So is this something that needs to be run during a build process? Is there no way to set this dynamically inline without a build process?

Comment: I have added the scripts way as well in the answer, you can look into it. If not, you have to explain a bit what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: The npm scripts are more of what I had in mind without knowing it... lol. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AlapanDas Is there a way to hide the URLs? I mean something like using environment variables instead of directly exposing the links.